# iOS 8.1.1 iPhone 4s Bad access on delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash, ios8.1

I have an app that runs fine on iPhone 4 iOS 6 on all iPhone 5 series iOS 7+ and 8+ 
But iPhone 4S with iOS 8.1.1 crashes on:

The `delegate` is `@property (nonatomic , assign)id delegate;` 
I tried to change it to `weak` but then I couldn't compile because of ARC disallowed this :(
Not sure , if I should convince the ARC to eat it or this is not even the issue :-/

```
 - (void) timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)timer
 {
    self.counter--;
    if( self.delegate != nil )
    {

        [self.delegate update:self.counter]; //at this row! ->`EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xc`
    }
    else
    {
        [self stop];
    }
}


0 objc_msgSend
1 -[countDownTimer timerFireMethod]
2 __NSFireTimer
...................................
9 UIAplicationMain
10 Main
11 start
```

NOTE: I am not using ARC :(

Can some1 point me what/where to look for this problem? 
Honestly I don't even know where to look :(

Comment: One object is deallocated. What is the type of counter ? try to access something else on the delegate to determine if it's delegate or counter that is deallocated. We'r almost in 2015 and you'r not using ARC, you got to have a really good reason !

Comment: as the message says that your delegate calling the method of deallocated object and also while checking for delegate methods use ` if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(update:)])` put a break point in `dealloc` method where u defined `update:` method and may be u get some hints

Comment: @BorisCharpentier the type of counter is int

ARC : I just got this project as is: and people who developed it before me did a lot of "WTF"s here .. P.S. I have no idea why ARC is not used here , however I can see that this project supports up to iOS 3

Comment: @Shan Thank for you advice I am going to check it immidiatly

Comment: @Shan BTW I have general question , Should I add this `if check` before every delegate I am using to avoid such problems in future ? is it a recommended habit ?

Comment: @Shan Okay , Now I added this line that u suggested , and the app crashed exactly with the same `BAD_ACCESSS` on the row that u suggested :'(

Comment: yes it is recommended to check it avoid crashes in many times it will be useful if u check like this,

Comment: did u put a breakpoint in dealloc method of  where u defined `update:` method, check if it is get calling before your delegate method

Comment: @Shan Yes I did! but the bad access occurred on `if(respondstoSelector ...)`

Comment: @Shan You are right it happens when I dealocing the object :(
if I will change the delegate from assign to weak will it handle the problem ?

Comment: bad access occurring because u are calling deallocated object's method that wy put a break point in the class where `update:` method is defined and check if it s calling before your delegate method

Comment: in that case choose a particular point to retain the object and after release it i can't tell by this , just retain it while allocating the object and release in deallocate in the above class that u are calling `update:` retain the object and release it in dealloc or (check if some where it is releasing manually .. if so comment release and try)

Comment: @Shan this is exactly what I did :( However.. still crashes.. 
Well Atleast thanks for pointing me to the problem, now I know what is the problem so I will the work around soon or late :)